# How to check if new value is different than old for nullable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, null, sql-update

The goal is to prevent updates for rows where the new value is identical to the old value (because the table has an auto-updated timestamp that I don't want reset).

The issue is that some columns are nullable, so New <> Old does not work since this results in NULL if either New or Old is NULL.

A workaround is using ISNULL but this doesn't work if the replacement value could be a valid value in the table:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET ColumnName = @newValue
WHERE ISNULL(ColumnName, 'ValueIsNull') <> ISNULL(@newValue, 'ValueIsNull')
```

The other way I found was comparing values and then checking XOR New and Old to see if either is NULL. This is not very clear, especially if you have to check multiple columns:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET ColumnName = @newValue
WHERE
    ColumnName <> @newValue
    OR (
        (ColumnName IS NULL AND @newValue IS NOT NULL)
        OR (ColumnName IS NOT NULL AND @newValue IS NULL)
    )
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I hope you have more predicates in your where clause. As posted this would update the entire table or no rows which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Are there values for `ColumnName` that would always be invalid? Just set your `ISNULL()` condition to an invalid value, or to an empty string (if that's not a valid value).

Comment: @SeanLange yes, good point! This was just what I threw together for an example, the real code has more predicates.

Comment: @SeanLange Technically, wouldn't it update every record except the ones that match @newValue. Regardless, I've always found that developing `UPDATE`s makes for a good opportunity to learn more than you ever wanted to know about `RESTORE`s and `TRANSACTION`s. :-)

Comment: @Shawn kind of depends on what is passed in. ;)

Comment: Standard SQL has `is distinct from`, but SQL Server doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this method because you can easily compare multiple columns simultaneously. Run this and you'll see that it only updates the row when the columns you care about change.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT, Val1 VARCHAR(20),Val2 VARCHAR(20),LastUpdated DATETIME,VersionNum INT)
DECLARE @Val1 VARCHAR(20)='test'
DECLARE @Val2 VARCHAR(20)='test2'
INSERT INTO @T1 (ID,Val1,Val2,LastUpdated,VersionNum) SELECT 1,@Val1,@Val2,GETDATE(),1

SELECT * FROM @T1

UPDATE @T1
SET Val1=@Val1,Val2=@Val2, LastUpdated=GETDATE(),VersionNum=VersionNum+1
WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(Val1,Val2)<>BINARY_CHECKSUM(@Val1,@Val2)

SELECT * FROM @T1

SET @Val1 ='test'
SET @Val2 ='Oooooo'

UPDATE @T1
SET Val1=@Val1,Val2=@Val2, LastUpdated=GETDATE(),VersionNum=VersionNum+1
WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(Val1,Val2)<>BINARY_CHECKSUM(@Val1,@Val2)

SELECT * FROM @T1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one trick:

```
UPDATE t
    SET ColumnName = @newValue
    FROM tableName t CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_values
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT val
                FROM (VALUES (ColumnName), (@newValue) )  v(val)
               ) v
         ) v
    WHERE num_values <> 1;
```

SQL Server doesn't support `IS DISTINCT FROM`.  But, aggregation has the right logic that you want.  If the values are equal or both `NULL`, then then the count is 1.  Otherwise, the count will be 0 or 2.